# jquery ui draggable in Internet Explorer(IE) - Object doesn't support this method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

When I try to execute the following code in IE:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", 1);
        google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.3");


  $(document).ready(function()        
  {            
    $("#main-dialog").draggable();        
  });    

</script>

<div id="main-dialog">    
  This is just some simple content 
</div>
```

I get the following error message:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's my ignorance of the google ajax API but where you load jquery with the parameter '1' try using '1.2.6' to make sure it's the latest version you're using. It may have a bug fix with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error, similar to this, turned out my custom jQuery UI download was missing some dependencies. Try going back to the jQuery UI site and download again, but check all the boxes.